# javascript dom td href

Tags: javascript

How can I get the href url from in the td with dom

```
<td class="left"><a href="index.php&del=3" onclick="return confirmnDelete()"><img src="delete.png" style="border: none"/></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really enough info given, but:

```
alert(document.getElementById("theTable").rows[0].cells[0].firstChild.href);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QaKmx/1

Answer (score 2):

It'd be helpful if you had an ID assigned to that anchor, but if you want to make no changes to markup:

```
var allCells = document.getElementByTagName("TD");
for(var i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++){
     if(allCells[i].className == "left"){
          if(allCells[i].firstChild && allCells[i].firstChild.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
     if(allCells[i].firstChild.onclick.toString().replace("return confirmDelete()", "") != allCells[i].firstChild.onclick.toString()){
     return allCells[i].firstChild.href;
}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use a dom manipulation library such as jquery? If so, then something like:

```
$('.left > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
})
```